# Tailwind rebuilding is taking too long on first run

Tags: npm, tailwind-css

I am using tailwind CLI for my project. when I run `npx tailwindcss -i assets/css/input.css -o assets/css/tailwind.css --watch` for the first time of the day it takes almost 15 minutes to compile and after that, it rebuilds normally.
I am working on one other project too but have no problem with tailwind there. I also tried re-installing node modules and tailwind but still did not work.

[image: check rebuilding time 727439ms almost 12 minutes]

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. My `tailwind.config.js` was searching for all files including the root which would also search `node_modules`

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './**/*.{ts,tsx,jsx,js}',
```

You can change it to either a `src` folder `'./src/**/*.{ts,tsx,jsx,js}'` and move all your files there or be explicit on your folders to search with `'./components/**/*.{ts,tsx,jsx,js}'` etc...

Hope this helps

Comment: Fwiw - this helped me. Went from many minutes down to 2.5 seconds.